# Discord.js Timer Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was just wondering how I can make a simple countdown command using ms, so that when someone types !timer (time) (s/m/h) it starts a timer for the requested amount of time, and once the countdown is over sends a message

Comment: What is your current approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to get the args variable and validate the command:

```js
//msg = <Message>
//client = <Client>

const time = ms(args[0]);
if(!time) return msg.channel.send("invalid time");

client.setTimeout(() => msg.channel.send("time up"), time);
```